# PDO - Test Of Empty Results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that should look for an entry.  If it's not in the database then enter in the data.  Otherwise it returns back the data and they can update any fields.  If there is an entry it will be only one.  This works great if the entry is in the table.  But I've tried checking for empty rows, doing row_count, etc and doesn't seem to work.  Right now I just have this in the code(sanitized to remove company table information):

```
$query1  = " SELECT Number, Notes, Qty1, Qty2  FROM test.notes ";
$query1 .= " WHERE Number = '$searchnumber' ";

$result1 = $conn1->query($query1);
    $conn1 = null;
    if($result1==null)
    {
        echo "Result is null</p>\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {           
        echo "Result is not null</p>\n";
        return $result1;
    }
```

If I take out the if check what I seem to get back is if it's found it returns the values correctly.  If it's not found the result seems to be the query string itself.  The check doesn't work.  Probably because it returns back the query string if it's not found.

I know it's something simple but just haven't found it.

Comment: Please wrap your column and table names in backticks. This will prevent a error called mysql reserved words used.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the result and check it? You could also use `fetchAll`

Comment: What does `doing row_count` mean? In PDO it is `rowCount()`. And you should not check `$result1` for an empty value as that will only happen when the query fails. Getting 0 rows back is not failure.

Comment: `$result == null` doesn't mean that there is no row returned !

Comment: @Michael you what to know whether the `number` is available or not using PDO?

Answer (score 0):

```
// if available  in  database
   $query="SELECT Number, Notes, Qty1, Qty2  FROM test.notes WHERE Number='".$searchnumber."'";
    $qnt =   $conn1->query($query);
     $coun = count($qnt->fetchAll());

          if($coun > 0){
        // available 
         echo "Result is available</p>\n";

          }else{
            //not available
            echo "Result is not available</p>\n";

          }
```

i Think you need something like this.

if this is not working fine,  try another aproach

```
 $queryi = $conn1->prepare("SELECT Number, Notes, Qty1, Qty2  FROM test.notes WHERE Number='".$searchnumber."' ");

             $queryi->execute();
            $qn=  $queryi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



            foreach ($qn as $row => $data) {

                 $in_use = $data['Number'];

               //echo $in_use ;


              }

           // evaluate
           if($in_use == NULL){
              //not avilable

            }else{
            // available

             }
```

Comment: The effect of doing the fetchAll seems to ruin the $qnt data.  So even thought $coun returns back and the logic works there is not data in $qnt now.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest doing something like this:

Establish your query

```
$query1  = " SELECT Number, Notes, Qty1, Qty2  FROM test.notes ";
$query1 .= " WHERE Number = '$searchnumber' ";
```

See if there's a result for the query, and no error

```
if ($res = $conn1->query($sql)) {

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {

        /* Issue the real SELECT statement and work with the results */
         $sql = "SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
       foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
           print "Name: " .  $row['NAME'] . "\n";
         }
    }
    /* No rows matched -- do something else */
  else {
      print "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Comment: @Michael - Updated my answer.

Comment: this is a horrible one

Answer (score -1):

After some trial and error I got this to work:

```
    $result1 = $conn1->query($query1);
    $count = $result1->fetchColumn();
    if($count == "")
    {
    //          echo "Result is null</p>\n";
        return "0";
    }
    else
    {           
    //          echo "Result is not null</p>\n";
        $result1 = $conn1->query($query1);
        return $result1;
    }
```

I had to change the setup to include:

```
$conn1->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, TRUE);
```

Probably not a clean way but it works for now.   Thanks for all the help.